# Is there any way to use my Samsung Galaxy S3 as USB modem on Ubuntu PC?

Tags: samsung, usb-modem

Ive already installed Nautilus and I can mount both my Internal and external memories on my Ubuntu PC, but I couldn't find how to use my Samsung as Modem. Is it possible? 
BTW, my most sincerest despite to Samsung for not including drivers for free software.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just enable USB tethering on your phone and Ubuntu will see an USB ethernet device on which your phone will provide an address on (DHCP). Don't use the USB-modem approach, that's much harder.

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boxU5hTr6uY) on how to enable it on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on where you bought it. If you got it with a contract from your provider, it might well be, that the Android version provided does not support [Tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering), because it was locked.

Comment: Thanks for a so quick answer. But I think my phone is not locked for tethering, since I've already tether with a WinOS PC using Kies only. I was just trying through Wifi with FoxFi, but is unussualy slow (don't know why).

Answer (score -1):

easy tether works great they have an Ubuntu client, I am using it on my phone.
its a cdma Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: There's no need for an app to enable tethering.